# Desktop disappears after logging in from suspend

Tags: suspend

On EOS6, suspend is broken on my laptop. After suspending (either by closing the laptop lid or remaining idle), the login screen appears as expected, but then the desktop disappears on login. I can activate multitasking view with the touchpad gestures or keyboard shortcut and the wallpaper and various desktops appear, but disappear again to a gray screen if I leave multitasking view. The only way to get back to a regular desktop is to force the laptop to power off by holding down the power button and then reboot.

Comment: Same issue here. Force powering off sucks especially when I have unsaved work. Are you using external monitor by chance? Add your hardware information just in case we can find a link. I'm on a 2015 13" Macbook Pro.

Comment: No external monitor, just the laptop screen. It's an Acer Aspire E15. It has a Geforce 940MX if that makes any difference. Thankfully it's not my primary computer, I also have a PC and don't ever need it to suspend. For now I'm just keeping it plugged in and have suspend disabled while plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

I can not help, but confirm I have the same issue on an old ThinkPad T420.

I deactivated automatic suspension for now and always shut down the Laptop fully.

Comment: Oddly enough I never had this issue on Hera. Hopefully it's addressed soon! I've had a few small gripes with Odin but overall it's been solid.